# How to read MYI, MYD, frm

Tags: mysql, excel, myisam, mydac

I'm complete beginner no experience with mySql at all.
I've got some MYD, MYI, frm files containing measurements done by my machine.
Could someone tell me step by step how to open those files? 
Ideally would be if someone would give me instruction on how to move data from  these to excel.

Comment: Those are raw data files from a MySQL Server database. Even an experienced professional would have problems trying to fetch info from them. How did you get those files in the first place? May you overlooking the possibility that you already  have a server running and you just need a [client program](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to connect to it?

Comment: HI Alvaro, Yes you are right there must be a server running as there are other software extracting info from that machine. Like I have mentioned from start I'm trying to research this from scratch not having any experience in the area. So what client program could I use to extract that data and what information about the server will I have to have to connect?

Comment: There're many but you can first try the one I suggested. It might not be the fastest but it's the official one. The data you need is the data Workbench asks for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. (from the mysql commandline tool) `CREATE DATABASE mytest;` -- .
2. (in the filesystem) copy those 3 files (foo.MYD, foo.MYI, foo.frm) into the directory called `mytest`.
3. (from the mysql commandline tool)  `SELECT * FROM mytest.foo;`

Then gripe at the user who gave you those files; that is *not* the way to pass MySQL data around.

Comment: for anyone wondering the directory can be found under this path `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\<your mysql version>\Data\mytest`

Comment: @RiungeMaina - Thanks.  But that varies with OS and MySQL version and, in relevant, Cloud provider.